# How to set auto-play for Youtube video?

Tags: php, html, youtube

I have the below code, using which I want to autoplay the YouTube video.  It works fine with normal HTML code, but with the below PHP code, I can't play it automatically.  What is wrong?

```
 if(!isset($_GET['vidid']))
  {
  echo  '<div class="leftcurtain" style="width: 60px; display: block;"><img src="images/2frontcurtain.jpg"/></div>';
  echo  '<div class="rightcurtain" style="width: 60px; display: block;"><img src="images/2frontcurtain.jpg"/></div>';
  echo '    <div class="visible">
  <iframe width="597" height="365" src="';
  echo get_vid_url($vid_id);
    if (get_vid_url($vid_id) == "http://www.youtube.com/embed/be9eQ21OLu0") echo '?autoplay=1'; 
    echo '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
<span id="dummy"></span> <a class="rope" href="#" style="top: 10px;"> <img src="images/rope.png"/> </a> </div>';
      }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this to your url

```
?autoplay=1
```

eg  . `<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/
oHg5SJYRHA0?autoplay=1" frameborder="0"
allowfullscreen></iframe>`

Answer (score 0):

Better way to include Youtube Videos is to use one of the Youtube APIs e.g. [Youtube iFrame API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference)

The example code shows additionally the autoplay function, which is fired when the player is ready.

```
function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
}
```

In general you should use another php markup:

```
<?php if(!isset($_GET['vidid'])) : ?>

<div class="leftcurtain" style="width: 60px; display: block;"><img src="images/2frontcurtain.jpg"/></div>
<div class="rightcurtain" style="width: 60px; display: block;"><img src="images/2frontcurtain.jpg"/></div>
<div class="visible">
      <iframe width="597" height="365" src="<?php echo (get_vid_url($vid_id) == "http://www.youtube.com/embed/be9eQ21OLu0") ? get_vid_url($vid_id).'?autoplay=1':get_vid_url($vid_id);?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
<span id="dummy"></span> 
<a class="rope" href="#" style="top: 10px;"> 
    <img src="images/rope.png"/> 
</a> 
</div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

for your code replace with   YOUR URL   you can chage it with  remove the  echo  autoplay  and  add it at teh end  of url without echo

```
http://www.youtube.com/embed/be9eQ21OLu0?autoplay=1
```